# Problem when importing a large .lar file in liferay 6.2 Portal?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I exported a lar file from a liferay 6.2 prod env the size is `3.6G,` I need this lar file to be imported in a test env( liferay 6.2 env also ) . The problem is when importing this large .lare file in the test env liferay portal it says that it cannot import this .lar file as the size is greater than `102400k.`

Please how could I import it/ or how could I increase the capability of my liferay test env in order to let me import this `3.6G.`

[image.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn3CG.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: As your question doesn't involve any custom code, it's [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow. I recommend bringing it to the Liferay forums

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for replying me.
I don't have code to put..
because I'm on browser liferay portal side..

Comment: I brought it to Liferay forums. thx